# Reshape numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `X` of shape (20000,3):

```
X = array([[  3,   8,   4],
           [  1,   2,   4],
           ...
           [  5,   8,   4],
           [  3,   9,   4]])
```

I want to drop the last 'column' (i.e. where the `4`s are located), to get something like this:

```
X = array([[  3,   8],
           [  1,   2],
           ...
           [  5,   8],
           [  3,   9]])
```

Do I need to use a list comprehension to do this (i.e. iterate over array elements, save results to a `list` and convert `list` to `array`, or can I use a built-in numpy function, such as `extract` or `where`?  Maybe you recommend something all together different?  Thank you.

Comment: You can try this : `y = X[:, :2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to pick out a slice of the original array:

```
X = np.array([[  3,   8,   4],
              [  1,   2,   4],
              [  5,   8,   4],
              [  3,   9,   4]])

newX = np.array(X[:,:-1])
```

Here I have chosen all rows and all but the last column of the original array. Then, in addition I have made it to a new array (the extra `np.array()` wrapping) in order to ensure it gets new memory. Otherwise it will just be a view of the original array and any updates to `newX` will also affect `X`.

Comment: why `np.array` for slicing `X`?

Comment: @Shai To ensure a new array and thereby new memory layout. It is not strictly necessary, but as I wrote in the answer, it prevents updates to the new array not affect the original one.

Answer (score 3):

Use `scipy` or `numpy`, 
specify the array, column_to_delete, row/column

```
scipy.delete(X, 2, 1)   #(np.array, index, axis)
numpy.delete(X, 2, 1) # would give the same result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
X = numpy.array([[  3,   8,   4],
           [  1,   2,   4],
           [  5,   8,   4],
           [  3,   9,   4]])
XX = X[:,:-1]
print(XX)

# [[3 8]
#  [1 2]
#  [5 8]
#  [3 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do slice op.

```
y = x[:,:2]
```